# High CPU on MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I currently have a growing website and my system does quite a lot of queries for each pageview. Recently I discovered that my MySQL server is getting a bit slower and the CPU is about 15% when I have around 40 users logged in at the same time. I started to search around a bit what settings I should have but didn't really quite get what the "optimal" settings should be. I have also checked my processlist and it has like 200 sleep queries. Any idea what might causing it?

ps. I have a lot of small scripts posting in the background (3 for every user/10 seconds) for every user, none that are too heavy load on.

My SQL config:

```
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 256M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 240K

join_buffer_size =256K
query-cache-type = 0
query-cache-size = 8
thread-cache-size = 50
open-files-limit = 65535
table-definition-cache = 1024
table-open-cache = 2048

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 824M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1

max_connections=500
max_user_connections=600
wait_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=400
long_query_time=10
```

Comment: _background (3 for every user/10 seconds) for every user, none that are too heavy load on._ - Maybe not a lot individually, but that's 120 calls per 10 seconds if you have 40 users logged in. What do these calls do? Can they not be combined into 1 call? Can you describe more what you mean by "_my system does quite a lot of queries for each pageview_"? "_CPU is about 15%_" - that may not be very bad, but we have no way of knowing because we don't know the limits of your server.

Comment: One of the calls checks if a user has done a update on another page (when a user starts a survey on the website it opens in a new tab for another website which sends a callback when it's completed and when it is, we need to check that from the first page), another is fetching a live inventory of data from one of our APIs (which can change every second) and the last one is is checking another API inventory.

And yes, all of them is required to do separately.

Comment: Your CPU usage doesn't seem abnormal to me when your application is doing so many things at a time.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide meaningful suggestions.

Comment: @oliverw No additional information posted = No suggestions to improve performance.